# Sub plots to show two graphs in the same axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]
[image]

I have two results from two data frame. One for best models , and another one for worst models. I would like to draw bar plots for each dat frame, and  show them in the same axis. Also, I am interested to annotate each bar with the numbers as well. For these, I have attempted to use arguments from Matplotlib's annotate function and pass the coordinates where the annotation shall be done. I wanted to draw sub plots for the above data, but not sure why it is not working. I appreciate your suggestions! Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# random test data
#x = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
#y = x ** 2
# data in a pandas frame with 2 columns
#df = pd.DataFrame([x, y]).T

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2) # (n rows, n cols)
plots1 = sns.barplot(x="Model", y="G-mean", data=BestBaseLine)

# Iterrating over the bars one-by-one
for bar in plots1.patches:

    # Using Matplotlib's annotate function and
    # passing the coordinates where the annotation shall be done
    plots1.annotate(format(bar.get_height(), '.2f'),
                (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
                    bar.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                size=10, xytext=(0, 5),
                textcoords='offset points')
plots2 = sns.barplot(x="Model", y="G-mean", data=WorstBaseLine)

# Iterrating over the bars one-by-one
for bar in plots2.patches:

    # Using Matplotlib's annotate function and
    # passing the coordinates where the annotation shall be done
    plots2.annotate(format(bar.get_height(), '.2f'),
                (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
                    bar.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                size=10, xytext=(0, 5),
                textcoords='offset points')


# Setting the title for the graph
plt.title("Example 2")
plt.show()
```

I got the following image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the ax1 and ax2 subplots and set the main graph for each. The annotations are given without any problem, so I think only the structure of the subplots is the cause.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

colors = ['#006400','#008000','#228b22','#2e8b57','#3cb371']
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colors))

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 15))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2)

plots1 = sns.barplot(x="Model", y="G-mean", data=BestBaseLine, ax=ax1)
# Iterrating over the bars one-by-one
for bar in plots1.patches:

    # Using Matplotlib's annotate function and
    # passing the coordinates where the annotation shall be done
    plots1.annotate(format(bar.get_height(), '.2f'),
                (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
                    bar.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                size=10, xytext=(0, 5),
                textcoords='offset points')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
ax1.set_title("Example 1")

plots2 = sns.barplot(x="Model", y="G-mean", data=WorstBaseLine, ax=ax2)
# Iterrating over the bars one-by-one
for bar in plots2.patches:

    # Using Matplotlib's annotate function and
    # passing the coordinates where the annotation shall be done
    plots2.annotate(format(bar.get_height(), '.2f'),
                (bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
                    bar.get_height()), ha='center', va='center',
                size=10, xytext=(0, 5),
                textcoords='offset points')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
ax2.set_title("Example 2")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to use sns.set(style="whitegrid")
plt.figure(2, figsize=(20,15)) and add custom color palette. But it is not working here!

Comment: Introduced styles, changed graph size, and added custom color palette settings.